# Mapping domain objects to urls in Restlet the "right" way

Tags: rest, restlet

I'm currently using Restlet to provide a REST API for access to a database with a number of related tables, using JPA + Hibernate as my persistence layer. For a concrete example, suppose I have the following object hierarchy within my JPA entities:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    Long id; // primary key
    List<Bar> bars;
    // Other Foo data
}

@Entity
class Bar {
   public Long id;
   // Bar data
}
```

In addition to being referenced by `Foo`s, `Bar`s can be referenced by other object types as well, so I'd like to expose their representations within their own URL hierarchy, as opposed to placing as sub-resources within a single `Foo`'s hierarchy. So in my case, I want the XML representation of a `Foo` to look something like:

```
<Foo>
    <bars>
        <Bar>http://example.com/bars/42</Bar>
        <Bar>http://example.com/bars/127</Bar>
    </bars>
    <!-- Other foo data representation -->
</Foo>
```

In Restlet, when configuring the `Router` for my application, I have the following configuration:

```
router.attach("/foo", ListAllFooResource.class);
router.attach("/foo/{id}", SingleFooResource.class);
router.attach("/bar", ListAllBarResource.class);
router.attach("/bar/{id}", SingleBarResource.class);
```

Here's where my dilemma comes in. From the resource level, I can't seem to find a way to figure out where the `SingleBarResource` was placed. When constructing a representation of Foo from my JPA entities, I'd like to grab the id for each `Bar` referenced by the `Foo` and construct a URL to place in the XML (or JSON) representation.

My question is: from within one `ServerResource` subclass, is there a way to ask the `Application` what URL another `ServerResource` subclass was mapped to? If that is possible, then I can use the `getRootRef()` method to construct a full path to the required resource.

I found [This thread from 2007](http://osdir.com/ml/java.restlet/2007-03/msg00024.html) asking pretty much the exact same question in which the consensus was to either:

1. Query some external object managing URL configuration for server resources (using Spring or something similar to provide configuration and instantiation)
2. One of the Restlet developers suggested placing a static or instance method on the resource itself.

(1) Seems a little clunky, and (2) seems like it has the same problem, in which we don't know at the resource level where it was placed by the application. Also, since the question was asked 6 years ago, there might be a better solution now.

I'm pretty new to Restlet and REST architectures in general, so I'm open to the possibility that I'm going about this entirely incorrectly, so feel free to tell me that.